# Increase terminal font size on focus

Tags: command-line, terminator, virtual-console

I can normally change terminal font size using mouse and +/-

I need multipane terminal with four panes/windows that the focused pane automatically increases font size on focus and restores the normal font size on losing focus.

I have looked into terminator but I find it hard decipher the api and into tmux but I'm open to any other suggestions, GNU Screen, Emacs, VS Code, anything.

It's for presentation purposes

Comment: I am not expert on this, but, assuming that the terminal will "prefer" to keep `COLUMS` and `LINES` unchanged, the terminal window will have to resize. Is this appropriate for presentation purposes? Anyway, you can have a look at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1110903/change-terminal-font-size-programatically

Comment: Which version and flavour of Ubuntu are you running? In Ubuntu Desktop there is `gnome-terminal`, and youo can easily shift font size (and window size) with 'ctrl +', 'ctrl -' and reset with 'ctrl 0'. But it does not happen automatically when you shift focus. And alternative is to have several tabs in `gnome-terminal` and shift tab (and all the time have big font). That way the audience witll focus on the tab that you are showing.

Comment: @fedkad That looks promising, thanks.

Comment: @sudosus Xubuntu 20.04. I'll do that if I don't find what I want. But it would be nice if I had 2x2 grid of terminals one terminal with Apache Kafka console producer and the other with a console consumer to pass events. It would be a nice feature. Or I'll just make all four terminal font bigger. Thanks just the same.

Comment: Since tmux is a terminal multiplexer, what you ask is definitely not possible using tmux (it works by using a single console window for multiple virtual windows and panes).

Comment: @Artur Meinild I (kind of) managed to make it work with a Terminator plugin. It will do the job anyway.

Comment: [The code is here](https://github.com/1-2-3-Data/terminator-zoom-on-focus/blob/main/my_plugin.py), if anyone stumbles upon this sthread.